# Stack Exchange-GIS Blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I was reading the Super-User blog was [looking for writers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2278/the-super-user-blog-is-looking-for-writers), and I was thinking it would be great to have a GIS-SE blog.

I imagine it would be something we would need to talk to the SE team about, and if it is something they would consider (if we ask, I imagine others will or already have).

I guess it begs the Q of who contributes blog posts?
Not sure if reputation should be tied to whether you can submit an article to the blog.

Im just thinking - Have read some great Q&As from individuals on this site.  I know a number of them have their own blogs, but a lot don't have the time to maintain a blog, and a GIS-SE blog would be a reputable site to contribute valuable blog posts to?

Ill have a bigger think about this, so may edit the question later, but the key Q im asking is:

**Whats peoples thought on having a GIS-SE blog?**
- What considerations would need to be considered.

Comment: I think ill wait till the Moderator elections are finished.  MIght be one for them to take on and perhaps have a chat room meeting to work out what purpose the blog would have and how to schedule posting to it.

Comment: See Rebecca's link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509

Other than the gathered thoughts on this post, would the next best step be to arrange a meetup in the chatroom some point soon?

Comment: I was just reading superuser blog - awesome stuff.   
http://blog.superuser.com/  
We need to get a meeting in chat room to work out how to do one for GIS.  How should we arrange this?

Answer (score 12):

Sure.

There are plenty of great topics for blog posts that can hopefully go far above and beyond being a mere reference answer for common questions

If this gets traction, coordinate with rebecca@stackexchange.com and she can get a provisional blog set up.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  
Every1 else = Shall I wait to see if I can get >10 votes on this Q, before hassling Rebecca?

Comment: @SimonJackson, no hassle!  We now have a concrete set of [guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91407/area-51-for-blogs/91509#91509) for communities interested in starting a blog.

Answer (score 10):

I like the idea that was recently floated (during a mod chat) to periodically write up a "question of the week."  In my imagination this would be a particularly interesting or popular question, answer, or series of comments that is highlighted and perhaps expanded upon by someone expert in the area.

Comment: +1 or maybe a list of top questions for the week, along with some excerpted quotes.  We should get James to make it part of the planetgs.com feed.

Comment: I would add that ability to add "tips/how-to" might also be useful...why wait for the question of the week when one might get the jump on it.

Answer (score 5):

This would be great, maybe we could get some 'canonical' answers explained in that blog!

Comment: I agree a good start would be to identify questions already mentioned on the site as "candidate" questions of the week (or at least emulate what we expect in the future) to get the ball rolling.